# How to know if HTML video play event fired by user click or auto-play?

Tags: html, html5-video, dom-events

There is a HTML video tag with `autoplay` property. I want to know when a `play` event fired, is it caused by auto-play, or is it caused by user click on the play button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't really a bullet-proof way of knowing the distinction out-of-the-box (unless I have overlooked a property for this).

One way to work around this in that case, is by using flag(s) at various stages. For example, set a flag on a `canplay` event on the video element which is cleared (expired) within a reasonable time frame which can then be used with the `play` event (I'll show an example in a moment).

As this is a bit "hackish" there can be special cases where the status slips through though, pre-loading and preparation time, quick users clicking the button etc. may all play part.

**A *conceptual* example:**

(note: for some reason, in the stack-snippet below the `play` event triggers on pause as well..).

As always, use at own risk!

```js
var video = document.querySelector("video");

var tref;                                         // to expire flag below
var autoPlay = false;                             // if we started by autoplay (expires)

video.addEventListener("canplay", function(e) {
  clearTimeout(tref);                             // reset expire
  autoPlay = this.autoplay;
  if (!autoPlay) document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = "Ready."; 
  setTimeout(function() {autoPlay = false}, 100); // clear autoPlay flag
});

video.addEventListener("play", function(e) {
  document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = autoPlay ? "Autoplay" : "Manual play";
});

video.src = "//media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4";
```

```css
video {width:320px}
```

```html
<div>Loading video...</div>
<video muted autoplay controls preload=auto></video>
```

Comment: There is a problem when I run the code snippet. Video `play` event fired before add event listener to it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @MartinZhai usually it can be solved by setting the src last (as in the example)

Comment: I found Chrome does not generate a `click` event when clicking on play/pause button. First I thought it is a new feature of latest version, but I tried on Chrome 40+, still the same. Do you have a solution to this?

Comment: @MartinZhai seems as that is blocked in Chrome/Opera (the control (shadow DOM) prevents bubbling the click event I guess). I came up with a new strategy and have updated the answer.